# Winforms Databinding on a generic property in a custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, data-binding, custom-controls

I have a generic custom control that contains a property as seen below:

```
public T Editing
{
    get { return _editing; }
    set
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(value, _editing))
            return;
        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateOnGuiThread(value)));
    }
}
```

I have tried databinding this property to a property on my controller object as seen below:

```
_customCtrl.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Editing", _controller, "CurrentItem"));
```

The controller class implements INotifyPropertyChanged and exposes the property like this:

```
public SpecialData CurrentItem
{
    get { return _currentItem; }
    set
    {
        _currentItem= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
    }
}
```

But as I broadcast `PropertyChanged` from my controller class the debugger will never enter in the setter of the `Editing` property. I've also tried the databinding below to no avail.

```
_customCtrl.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Editing", _controller, "CurrentItem", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

I've read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233813(v=vs.80).aspx and tried using the `DefaultBindingPropertyAttribute` but it doesn't help either.

Does anybody know how to get this binding to work? I thought that the binding manager would propagate the value from the controller to the control's property as PropertyChanged is broadcast in the controller class (just like a simple textbox text binding).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: What is the actual `T` of the `_customCtrl` and is there a conversion from `SpecialData` to it?

Comment: They are the same type. It is a class type

Answer (score 0):

You should always create your bindings with [FormattingEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.formattingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to `true`. Note that `FormattingEnabled=false` is just for backward compatibility and unfortunately is the default.

Either use one of the `Binding` constructor (or `ControlBindingsCollection.Add`) overloads that have a `formattingEnabled` parameter or set the property afterwards. In your case, something like this

```
_customCtrl.DataBindings.Add("Editing", _controller, "CurrentItem", true);
```